# Как запускать thread при начале работы бота telebot?

Tags: python, telebot, threading

Я создаю поток в боте:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    # ..код..
    Thread(target=sub_expiration_handler, args=[message]).start()
```

Всё работает как я и задумывал, но я в будущем планирую накатывать обновы на бота, а для этого придётся его перезапускать, при этом поток возобновиться, только когда пользователь введёт команду `/start`, а мне хотелось бы начинать его с самого начала работы бота.
Очевидно, можно запускать поток в самом начале, вне `start`, но тогда непонятно, как передать аргумент `message`.

Comment: Мне просто интересно, а зачем вам вообще поток для каждого пользователя?!

Comment: Мне нужно реализовать проверку истечения подписки и присылать уведомления нужному пользователю, если она кончается. Единственный способ, который я придумал, это для каждого пользователя запускать отдельный поток с бесконечным циклом внутри и сравнением текущей даты с датой истечения подписки

Comment: Но это глупо, представьте у вас будет 100, тысяча юзеров или больше и под каждого создавать поток? Ваш бот залагает и умрет. К тому же каждый пользователь нажмет на кнопку старт еще пару раз и создаст доп мусорных потоков, а вы этого никак не предусматриваете. Мой вам совет, создайте лучше отдельный поток(один), который раз в сутки (скажем в 00:00) парсит бд ваших подписчиков и у кого заканчивается подписка, тем и рассылает письма счастья. Это куда проще и надежнее чем городить неконтролируемую гору потоков.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, это правда хорошая идея